# Is there any way to get the creation date of CloudBlobDirectory instance?

Tags: azure, directory

Is there any way to get the creation date of CloudBlobDirectory instance in azure blob storage?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately CloucBlobDirectory is not and object that is explicitly created, it's just a prefix. So the only way to tell when it has been created is to check all the blobs with this prefix and find min created date. This approach is not perfect, because the first blob could have been deleted and "min create date" of the directory will be create date of the next in the list.